# VBA table manipulation - leave CAD only

Tags: excel, vba

I have a step like this: In "Subscription" tab, working on rows between and including row with cell with text "TRUE" and cell with text "TRUE Total" in column A, delete every row until you reach "CAD" in column B. Skip row with "CAD" in column B and 3 rows below it. Then delete every row below those 4 rows until you reach the row with "TRUE Total" in column A.

---

OK, F it, there's a whole code for the whole process. Guys, please help with that CAD as I'm loosing my mind....

```vb
Sub XXX()
Dim filePath As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wsResult As Worksheet, wsSubscription As Worksheet, wsRedemption As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long
    
    ' Step 1: Prompt to open file
    filePath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
    If filePath = "False" Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Step 2: Open workbook and sheets
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filePath)
    Set wsResult = wb.Sheets("Result")
    
    ' Step 3: Copy and paste columns A:D as values with formatting
    wsResult.Range("A:D").Copy
    wsResult.Range("A:D").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    
    ' Step 4: Create "Subscription" and "Redemption" tabs
    Set wsSubscription = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wsResult)
    wsSubscription.Name = "Subscription"
    Set wsRedemption = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wsSubscription)
    wsRedemption.Name = "Redemption"
    
    ' Step 5: Copy rows to "Subscription" tab
    lastRow = wsResult.Cells(wsResult.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To lastRow
    If wsResult.Cells(i, "A").Value = "TRUE Total" Then Exit For
    wsResult.Rows(i).Copy wsSubscription.Cells(i - 2, 1)
    Next i

                            ' Step 6: Delete rows in the "Subscription" tab as per the new requirement
                            
    ' Continue with the code for deleting rows in the "Subscription" tab
Dim rowToDelete As Range
Dim foundCAD As Boolean, foundTrueTotal As Boolean

' Loop through rows starting from row 3
For i = 3 To wsSubscription.Cells(wsSubscription.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If wsSubscription.Cells(i, "B").Text = "CAD" Then
        foundCAD = True
        Set rowToDelete = wsSubscription.Rows(i)
        Exit For
    End If
    Set rowToDelete = wsSubscription.Rows(i)
Next i

' Delete rows until reaching "CAD" in column B
If foundCAD Then
    Do Until rowToDelete.Cells(1, "B").Text = "CAD"
        rowToDelete.Delete
    Loop
End If

' Loop through rows starting from row 7
For i = 7 To wsSubscription.Cells(wsSubscription.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    If wsSubscription.Cells(i, "A").Text = "TRUE Total" Then
        foundTrueTotal = True
        Set rowToDelete = wsSubscription.Rows(i)
        Exit For
    End If
    Set rowToDelete = wsSubscription.Rows(i)
Next i

' Delete rows until reaching "TRUE Total" in column A
If foundTrueTotal Then
    Do Until rowToDelete.Cells(1, "A").Text = "TRUE Total"
        rowToDelete.Delete
    Loop
End If


' Step 7: Copy rows to "Redemption" tab
    For i = 1 To lastRow
    If wsResult.Cells(i, "A").Value = "FALSE" Then Exit For
    Next i
    For j = i To lastRow
    If wsResult.Cells(j, "A").Value = "Grand Total" Then Exit For
    Next j
    wsResult.Rows(i & ":" & j).Copy wsRedemption.Cells(1, 1)
    
    ' Step 8: Add formula to "Redemption" tab
    For i = 3 To wsRedemption.Cells(wsRedemption.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row Step 4
    wsRedemption.Cells(i, "E").Formula = "=CONCATENATE(""REDS-"", $B$" & (i + 1) & ", "" NEW"")"
    Next i
    
    ' Step 9: Hide rows with "USD" in column B in "Redemption" tab
    lastRow = wsRedemption.Cells(wsRedemption.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastRow
    If wsRedemption.Cells(i, "B").Value = "USD" Then
    wsRedemption.Rows(i).Resize(4).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    i = i + 4 ' Skip the next 3 hidden rows
    End If
    Next i
    
    ' Step 10: Delete columns A:E in "Result" tab
    wsResult.Range("A:E").Delete xlShiftToLeft
    
    ' Step 11: Copy rows from "Subscription" tab to "Result" tab
    wsSubscription.Rows("1:5").Copy wsResult.Cells(3, 1)
    
    ' Step 12: Copy rows from "Redemption" tab to "Result" tab
    lastRow = wsRedemption.Cells(wsRedemption.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastRow
    If wsRedemption.Cells(i, "A").Value = "Grand Total" Then Exit For
    Next i
    wsRedemption.Rows("1:" & i).Copy wsResult.Cells(wsResult.Cells(wsResult.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 5, 1)
    
    ' Step 13: Adjust column width
    wsResult.Columns("A:E").AutoFit
    
    ' Step 14: Format columns
    wsResult.Columns("A:C").NumberFormat = "General"
    wsResult.Columns("E").NumberFormat = "General"
    wsResult.Columns("D").NumberFormat = "_($* #,##0.00_);_($* (#,##0.00);_($* ""-""??_);_(@_)"
    
    ' Step 15: Delete "Subscription" and "Redemption" tabs
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' To suppress confirmation dialogs
    On Error Resume Next ' Ignore errors if sheets do not exist
    wb.Sheets("Subscription").Delete
    wb.Sheets("Redemption").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0 ' Reset error handling
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    ' Step 16: Stay on "Result" tab
    wsResult.Activate
    
    ' Step 17: Prompt to save the file
    Dim savePath As String
    savePath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="YourFileName.xlsx", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
    If savePath <> "False" Then
    Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show savePath, xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, because when you delete line-by-line the line numbering always change.

```
    If startRow > 0 And endRow > 0 And cadRow > 0 Then
        
        Range(Rows(cadRow + 4),Rows(endRow)).Delete
        Range(Rows(startRow),Rows(cadRow - 1)).Delete
   
    End If
```

Doesn't see the assignment of the wsSubscription variable

```
Set wsSubscription = Worksheets("Subscription")
```

in the Declaration part.

Answer (score 0):

your code has two issues

- you don't have to `Exit For` after finding out "CAD" row
- you have to delete rows in "backwards" mode, otherwise your rows indexes would loose their reference

consider this code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim startRow As Long
    Dim endRow As Long
    Dim cadRow As Long
    Dim skipRows As Long
    startRow = 0
    endRow = 0
    cadRow = 0
    skipRows = 3
    
    Dim wsSubscription As Worksheet
    Set wsSubscription = Worksheets("Subscription")
    With wsSubscription
        Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long
        
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 1 To lastRow
            Select Case True
                Case Cells(i, "A").Text = "TRUE"
                    startRow = i
                Case Cells(i, "B").Text = "CAD"
                    cadRow = i
                Case Cells(i, "A").Text = "TRUE Total"
                    endRow = i
                    Exit For
            End Select
        Next i
        
        If startRow > 0 And endRow > 0 And cadRow > 0 Then
        
            .Rows(cadRow + skipRows + 1).Resize(endRow - (cadRow + skipRows + 1) + 1).Delete
            
            .Rows(startRow).Resize(cadRow - startRow).Delete
            
        End If
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: For some reason it still doesn't work. It leaves 4 rows, true, but with text EUR.

Comment: and how'd it end?

Comment: This misery doesn't end my friend...